# Writing data into a HTML template

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, html-parsing

I have a HTML template in my project's bundle. It is structured in such a way that i need to pass arguments to the various %@'s as shown

```
@"<h3>Test</h3>"
"<div style=\"color:#000;margin:5px;padding:4px;font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-LtCn;font-size:16;\">Name: %@</div>"
"<div style=\"color:#000;margin:5px;padding:4px;font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-LtCn;font-size:16;\">City: %@</div>"
"<div style=\"color:#000;margin:5px;padding:4px;font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-LtCn;font-size:16;\">Country: %@</div>"
```

I have done similar functionality, wherein my template was an XML file and i used DDXMLParser to write to the template. Is there any such parser which will let me write to an HTML template.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the string from the file first, and then replace it using `stringWithFormat:`

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];

// Read whole content
NSData *data = [fileHandle readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *templateString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
[fileHandle closeFile];

// Replace here
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:templateString, param1, param2, param3];
```

Comment: I want to replace string only as a last resort.The snippet i've posted is just a sample.In reality, its going to be a pretty huge HTMl.so is there any other way..

Answer (score 1):

Just use normal string interpolation

```
NSString *template = @"<h3>Test</h3>"
    "<div style=\"color:#000;margin:5px;padding:4px;font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-LtCn;font-size:16;\">Name: %@</div>"
    "<div style=\"color:#000;margin:5px;padding:4px;font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-LtCn;font-size:16;\">City: %@</div>"
    "<div style=\"color:#000;margin:5px;padding:4px;font-family:HelveticaNeueLTPro-LtCn;font-size:16;\">Country: %@</div>";

NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:template, @"Paul", @"Leeds", @"UK"]);
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works fine.. but is there any other way than string interpolation. The snippet is just a test string

Comment: What is your concern with the approach above? It's hard to tell what you need without more details...

Comment: The concern is that the string i am going to render contains HTML tables which i dynamically need to add to the template. I was not sure whether this was the right approach or whether HTML parsers like HPPLE could be used. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't really sound like you are traversing or manipulating the DOM so I'm not sure why you feel you need this?